# Hard Disk recovery

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have 3 disks of the same type model and year of production. All the disks were used part of a generic solution of an IBM server solution.

My problem is that all 3 disks suffered the same malfunction at the same exact time and are now dis-functional.

I went to two different expert’s laboratories and got the same answer:

To recover the data they need another identical disk from which they can take spare parts. *Can my case really be that clinical?*

Anyway, I am not sure if this question belongs to this forum, but I am looking to buy the following disk:

```
IIBM ESERVER XSERIES  
IBM P/N 24P3707  
IBM FRU 24P3708  
146.8GB USCSI  
10K RPM  
PART NOMBER 9V2005-027
```

I already bought a disk with the same part number, but the labs said that apparently I need a disk that was manufactured in the same factory. That means that all the numbers have to be exactly the same.

If anybody know where I can purchase such a disk (the information on the lost disks is really important to me), please tell me the place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can my case really be that clinical?

Good question. It makes little sense. You obviously have a electronic or mechanical problem with your disks (a power surge probably being that it happened to all at the same time. But it's irrelevant for me to speculate). In any case their intent seem to be to replace the damaged parts with identical ones.

However, disks aren't such a bigot piece of hardware that can't take parts from other similar models in order to function well enough to move on to the data recovery process. More so because you are only interested on said data recovery (not on recovering the disks themselves... right?). So it's even more odd when they go to the point of requesting the disk to have been manufactured on the same factory despite the part number being the same. I find no explanation for that, other than them trying to cover themselves from any accidental damage finally rendering the recovery impossible.

I'm not sure who you are talking with to do this, but I'd probably suggest to go somewhere else. Go online and search for other options for data recovery. **Good data recovery centers don't ask anything from their customers and take matters on their hands**.

---

In any case, **to answer your question directly** no one in here will be able to provide you with a satisfactory answer, I think. Unless they happen to work on any of IBM's hardware departments. That's where I suggest you to go. Contact IBM directly with the information about those disks in your hand and explain to them the problem. They are your best hope for said exact same-everything these two data recovery centers are asking from you.

---

For **Data recovery Centers in Europe**, you can hardly miss with the folks at [Ontrack](http://www.ontrackdatarecovery.com/data-recovery-services/). They have facilities a little across the whole continent as well as in North America, Asia and Oceania.

If the price isn't right for you, you can dig deeper and go to [IPDRA](http://www.ipdra.org/) (International Professional Data Recovery Association) and look at [their directory](http://www.ipdra.org/data-recovery-directory/).

Meanwhile, I have personally used [DRC](http://www.datarecovercenter.com/) services in the past with a high satisfaction rate and fair price.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would have given you a vote up, but I can't at the moment. Do you know of any recovery center in Europe that you can recommend. Specifically, a center that works with IBM disks? The labs I tried are "Tik Tak" and "MITsy". One said it cannot recover the data and the other asked for the same drive...
Just to give them some slack, they did not give a big estimation even though I was willing to pay.

Comment: Sure. Editing my answer with more information...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into this!
Since this does answer a great part of my question, marking it.

Answer (score 1):

The company that suggests you get them identical disks is only covvering their *rse. If you would bring any other disk and it might fail due to that, they will be to blame.

My best guess is that you can use any other disk from the same manufacturer and the same production line and put the real disks in a new casing. **It will be expensive as hell though!!!**

> Why don't you have backups?

Comment: The thing is that those were the backups as well as the production disk. 2 disks working with mirroring and one a late night backup (another mirror). The data on the disks is worth quite a bit. I know - you learn from your mistakes... Next time the backup will be better.

Comment: RAID is never a decent Backup strategy,... just hw redundancy! ;) I can imagina it being worth quite a lot. But loads of companies offer data recovery, usually PER GB and they do not worry about what disks you have. Google it, I found 4 at least in my city (Amsterdam)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd update what happened eventually.
I used the services of a company called i365 (1 Heddon Street • Mayfair • London • W1B 4BD • UK). They had the same exact HD to use for spare parts. The price was reasonaly as well and they did an excellent job.

Thanks for all of the suggestion!

Comment: upvoted your question instead, you should use the edit feature for updates :)